# Showing and hiding multiple divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user rolls over a certain `<td>`, an iframe nested in a `<div>` slides down inside that `<div>`. Right now I have three `<div>`'s stacked on top of each other, and with jQuery I am showing and hiding the appropriate `<div>`.

It works fine if I let each `<div>` appear and then move my cursor to the next `<td>`, but if I move rapidly to each link, they load together and the jQuery does not properly hide the other `<div>`'s.

Here is the project site:

Click on "MPC Clients" dropdown, then hover the three links:

[Project Site](http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/project.html)

Here is the jQuery that I'm using:

```
$("td#version1").hover(function() {
    $("#iframe2,#iframe3").hide();
    $("#iframe1").slideDown("slow");
    $("#iframe2,#iframe3").hide();
});

$("td#version2").hover(function() {
    $("#iframe1,#iframe3").hide();
    $("#iframe2").slideDown("slow");
    $("#iframe1,#iframe3").hide();
});

$("td#version3").hover(function() {
    $("#iframe1,#iframe2").hide();
    $("#iframe3").slideDown("slow");    
    $("#iframe1,#iframe2").hide();
});
```

Here's the html with the hidden `<div>`'s:

```
<tr>
    <td id="previewWindow0" class="previewWindow" colspan="3"><h2>Preview Window</h2>
        <div id="iframe1"><iframe src="http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/liveWebinar.html"></iframe></div>
        <div id="iframe2"><iframe src="http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/MissedWebinar.html"></iframe></div>
        <div id="iframe3"><iframe src="http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/Mobile.html"></iframe></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you move over the elements fast multiple events are fired and animations are not complete so you don't see the expected behavior.

Use `stop()` method to stop the previous animation before you start the next.

Try this.

```
    $("td#version1").hover(function() {
        $("#iframe2,#iframe3").hide();
        $("#iframe1").stop(true, true).slideDown("slow");
        $("#iframe2,#iframe3").hide();
    });
    $("td#version2").hover(function() {
        $("#iframe1,#iframe3").hide();
        $("#iframe2").stop(true, true).slideDown("slow");
        $("#iframe1,#iframe3").hide();
    });
    $("td#version3").hover(function() {
        $("#iframe1,#iframe2").hide();
        $("#iframe3").stop(true, true).slideDown("slow");    
        $("#iframe1,#iframe2").hide();
    });
```

`stop(clearQueue, jumpToEnd)` reference - http://api.jquery.com/stop/